# activeStyle of <NavLink/> doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I use  tag for creationg navigation menu, but activeStyle attribute doesn't change background color of selected link:

I try to implement example from React and Redux book, page 289

```
const selectedStyle = {
backgroundColor: "white",
color: "slategray"
}

    export const MainMenu = () =>
<nav className="main-menu">
  <NavLink to="/">
  <HomeIcon/>
</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="about" activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [About]
</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="events" activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [Events]
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="products" activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [Products]
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="contact" activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [Contact Us]
</NavLink>
</nav>
```

is from "react-router-dom"

Comment: Please add `selectedStyle `

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **active class/style will only be applied if the location is matched exactly**

**put `exact` attribute with every `NavLink`.**

You have define `/` route which getting successfully mapped against each `NavLink` route path.So,there is no exact route matching.Hense no`activeStyle` applied.

```
 <NavLink to="/" exact>
  <HomeIcon/>
</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/about" exact activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [About]
</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/events" exact activeStyle={selectedStyle}>
  [Events]
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thank you! There is "/" character is mandatory in to="..." when use active style. Works without exact.

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov could u please one NavLInk u corrected

Comment: <NavLink to="/events" activeStyle={active}>
        [Events]
</NavLink>

Comment: ooops I have added this point in my answer  with script but not mentioned there with text